# Redirect users with rewrite rules when using hosts file to map subdomains to localhost on Apache server

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, rewrite, subdomain, docker-compose

I am running an Apache 2.4 server in using `docker-compose`.

I have a "main" vhost which includes rewrites paths which start with `/test/` to a `test` subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule "^/test/(.*)$" "http://test.example.com/$1" [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

The `test` subdomain does not exist, and cannot be created (for business reasons which are irrelevant to the issue). The way I accomplish resolving `test.example.com` is to include hosts entries in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    test:
        image: httpd:2.4
        ports:
            - 80:80
        extra_hosts:
            - "test.example.com:127.0.0.1"
```

This works, however in the vhost for `test.example.com` I have another rewrite rule:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.example.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:COOKIE} ^.*cookie=([^;]+)
        RewriteRule /login /dashboard [R=302]
</VirtualHost>
```

This rule correctly rewrites `http://test.example.com/login` to `http://test.example.com/dashboard` on a successful login, but then the redirect happens in the user's browser and `http://test.example.com` cannot be resolved (`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`).

How can I perform this rewrite in the `test.example.com` vhost so that it correctly redirects the user to the `/dashboard` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the redirect to the config for example.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:COOKIE} ^.*cookie=([^;]+)
    RewriteRule "^/test/login/?$" "/test/dashboard" [R=302]

    RewriteRule "^/test/(.*)" "http://test.example.com/$1" [P]
</VirtualHost>
```